# Trying to install Distutils and receiving an error that I need distutils.core

Tags: setuptools, distutils

I am trying to install Distutils and receiving an error that I need distutils.core.  I have no package manager so no apt-get or yum.  How can I get the distutils.core installed onto my system?  I can only find references to the module but apparently there appears to be no way to just download the files. I am running python2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[distutils](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/distutils.html) is a part of Python standard library since the dawn of time. You don't need to install the package, it must always be available. If it's not available your standard library is broken and should be fixed, perhaps by reinstalling.

If you're trying to install [this Distutils](https://pypi.org/project/Distutils/) — it's a very old version from 2007. Forget about it.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the help.  Unfortunately the standard package has been "broken" as everything has been removed on this device for security reasons.  Lol  so I will just have to try and find a way to get something to work as it even has no compiler.  Just trying to add the azure agent so I can add the vm into an Azure lab.  What a pain this has been.

Comment: @Jeff Just copy the entire directory from the latest source distribution or from Python git repository.